# Dados da busca do Mysql Gravar em variaveis PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Quero pegar o valor de uma consulta no `mysql`

```
SELECT lamp_estado, lamp_descricao FROM lampadas ORDER BY lamp_id
```

E gravar cada valor encontrado na busca, em uma variável.
Eu estou usando este comando mais ele ta gravando apenas o último valor da busca.

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $estado=$row["lamp_estado"];
        $descricao=$row["lamp_descricao"];
        $estado2=$row["lamp_estado"];
        $descricao2=$row["lamp_descricao"];
    }
}
```

Comment: Da forma que está a fazer com `$estado=$row["lamp_estado"];` substitui sempre o anterior, assim como está a ler os 2 campos que vem da tabela duas vezes. Como pretendia usar o resultado ?

Comment: Olá Joao Claudio, não se esqueça de marcar a resposta que solucionou seu problema como aceita, veja como e porque isso é importante nesse post  https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta/1079#1079

Comment: Vou usar 10 variáveis, para criar 10 botões cada botão vai ligar uma lampada to usando bd para ter controle delas. Preciso saber o estado que elas estão, por isso precisava deste comando. ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Armazene todos os dados da consulta em um array.**

```
$array = array();

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $array[] = $row;
}

 //exemplo retornado
//Array ( [0] => Array ( [lamp_estado] => estado AAA [lamp_descricao] => lâmpadas LED ) [1] => Array ( [lamp_estado] =>estado BBB [lamp_descricao] => lâmpadas fluorescentes ) [2] => Array ( [lamp_estado] => estado CCC [lamp_descricao] => lâmpadas tubulares ) .....
```

**E para acessar os elementos do array:**

```
$estado = $estado2 = $array[1]['lamp_estado'];
echo $estado;   //estado BBB
echo $estado2; //estado BBB

$descricao = $descricao2 = $array[1]['lamp_descricao];
echo $descricao;  //lâmpadas fluorescentes
echo $descricao2; //lâmpadas fluorescentes
```

---

---

> Esclarecendo esse problema de `ta gravando apenas o último valor da busca`

Imagine uma tabela cuja coluna é denominada de "lampadas" e a seta (->) é o ponteiro da lista.

```
-> lâmpadas LED
   lâmpadas fluorescentes
   lâmpadas tubulares
```

Quando utilizamos a função `$result->fetch_assoc()`, ele retorna a primeira linha:

```
   while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
   $estado=$row["lamp_estado"];
```

Neste momento a variável **$estado** assume o valor **lâmpadas LED** e o ponteiro move-se uma posição para frente, e nossa lista fica da seguinte maneira:

```
   lâmpadas LED
-> lâmpadas fluorescentes
   lâmpadas tubulares
```

Neste momento a variável **$estado** assume o valor **lâmpadas fluorescentes** e o ponteiro move-se uma posição para frente, e assim sucessivamente.

> Então é por isso que no seu while na variável `$estado`, bem como as outras variáveis, só aparece o último nome.

Ao executar o `while` o valor da variável `$estado` está sendo sobrescrito porque você não está concatenando os valores.

Você pode por exemplo fazer assim para concatenar

```
$estado = $estado.",".$row["lamp_estado"];
```

o que resultaria em uma string com os dados separados por virgula.

Answer (score 0):

Isso ocorre porque você esta sobrepondo a informação.

Uma variável simples não consegue armazenar informações separadas, para fazer isso a variável tem que ser um `array`, ou seja, uma lista de variáveis.

Quando você faz:

```
$estado = $row["lamp_estado"];
```

A variável `$estado` irá receber o valor da coluna `lamp_estado` da linha atual, se houver um valor na variável `$estado`, esse valor será perdido.
Você resolve esse problema de perda de informação criando um `array`(lista) de estados:

```
$estado = array();
$descricao = array();
$estado2 = array();
$descricao2 = array();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $estado.push($row["lamp_estado"]);
    $descricao.push($row["lamp_descricao"]);
    $estado2.push($row["lamp_estado"]);
    $descricao2.push($row["lamp_descricao"]);
}
```

O comando `push` é responsável por adicionar um item ao `array`, ele faz a variável do tipo `array` alocar mais um espaço na memória para armazenar uma nova variável.

Para você escrever o nome do segundo estado por exemplo, terá que pegar o conteúdo do segundo espaço da variável `$estado`. Como um `array` inicia a contagem dos espaços em `0`, a posição do segundo espaço da variável `$estado` é `1`:

```
echo $estado[1];
```